# How we can find an Telegram API bot domain link from bot id?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Is there anyway to find an Telegram API bot (domain link) from that bot id ?
I only know a Telegram user id and I want to know how can I find that telegram bot domain link and host.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the webhook url by user-id Or bot-id.

Use `getWebhookInfo` to get the webhook if you have the bot token.

It'll cause a security problems if users was who sending the updates to the bot.

If you mean the domain chosen via `/setdomain` command via @BotFather, Then you can't unless the bot requires you to login to a website via button.